# Why does Post action work in Postman, not in C#

Tags: c#, api, get

I am trying to execute a GET command so I get can get data from a server. The Curl below works in Postman.

```
$ curl -X GET -H "Authorization: {SESSION_ID}" \
https://{server}/api/{version}/metadata/vobjects
```

While running my code, I am able to get the session ID. The next step is to get the data. But when I execute the GET, I don't get any response. Instead a I get an error as follows: "Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters. (Parameter 'name')"

Below is the C# code I am trying to execute

```
public static void getObjects(string sessionID)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://generic-server.com/api/v20.3/metadata/vobjects/");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization:", sessionID);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine("Here's the response: "  + response.Content + " " + response.Content.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Here's the error message: " + response.ErrorMessage);
        }
```

**Problem:** I get no response from the server and the response length is zero.

> Here's the response:  0

response.ErrorMessage gives the following:

> Here's the error message: Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters. (Parameter 'name')

Note: When I leave the colon out of of the header, then I get the following response from the server:

> {"responseStatus":"FAILURE","errors":[{"type":"INVALID_DATA","message":"Invalid http header [Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml]"}]} 190

Comment: so have you used fiddler to compare the request ?

Comment: I think you should drop colon out of the header and as an advice you can test adding 'Accept:application/json' header to the request.

Comment: @NavidRsh How would you structure the curl command?

Comment: @00110001 I compared the fiddler output. It says I have a session ID in postman and not in C#. Im not sure why it would say that given that I have a session ID

Comment: @vincetaylor70 I know the curl command does not have that header, but the error message says something about this header, I think it's worth a try at least.

Comment: Thank you at @NavidRsh yours was the solution after much trying

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ("Authorization", $"Bearer {sessionID"});